# Can someone break down this unix grep and awk statement?

Tags: shell-script, awk, grep

Can someone break down this statement?

```
sFileName=`ls -lrt $sTmpPath/$1* | grep ^- | grep -v grep |  head -1 | awk 'BEGIN { FS="/" } { print $NF }'`
```

Here

1. `$sTmpPath` contains any temporary path in the unix server.
2. The first parameter passed is file name.

Thanks
Gautam

Answer (score 3):

- `ls -lrt`: lists its non-directory arguments and the **contents** of its directory arguments in `l`ong format in `r`everse `t`time (modification time) order (so from oldest to newest). Should have been `ls -lrtd --`.
- `$sTmpPath/$1*`: should have been `"$sTmpPath/$1"*`: the intention was to list the files in `$sTmpPath` whose name starts with `$1` I suppose.
- `grep ^-`. Better as `grep '^-'`  as `^` is special in several shells. Retains the lines that start with `-`. In the output of `ls -l`, that's the lines for **regular** files to the exclusion of any other type of file (directory, symlink, socket...). It could also give false positives if some file names or symlink targets contain newline characters.
- `grep -v grep`. Exclude lines that contain `grep`. Possibly whoever wrote that was thinking of the `ps | grep -v grep` trick. It makes no sense here.
- `head -1`. Ancient form of `head -n 1`: selects first line of input. So the line for the oldest matching file.
- `BEGIN{FS = "/"}`: set the awk field separator to `/`. You'd rather use `-F/` for that.
- `{print $NF}`: prints the last `/`-delimited field, so the part of the line after the last `/`, so the file name. Note that `awk` can do `grep` and `head`'s job.

So it seems the intent of the script is to report the oldest regular file in `$sTmpPath` whose name starts with the contents of `$1`.

It can be simplified and partly corrected to:

```
ls -nrtd -- "$sTmpPath/$1"* | awk -F/ '/^-/ {print $NF; exit}'
```

Here using `-n` instead of `-l` to avoid the unnecessary translation of uid/gids to username/groupname.

Note that it assumes none of the file names or symlink targets contain newline characters.

With `zsh`, you'd simply use `oldest=($sTmpPath/$1*(.Om[1]:t))`.

Comment: Got it...Thank you @Stéphane Chazelas